# Вставка стобца Excel файла в существующий Excel-файл

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Задача состоит в том чтобы из первого Excel файла вставить столбец во второй файл уже наполненный информацией, причем во втором файле создать столбец между уже заполненными столбцами чтобы не затереть их. 
Пожалуйста посоветуйте подходящую для этого библиотеку для java.

Comment: а что пробовали вы?

Comment: michael_best Пробовал Apache poi библиотеку, читал мануал но не нашел подходящей функциональности.